# Alternative for Subquery Other Than a View

Tags: mysql, sql, database, view, subquery

Thanks for looking at my post, any help/guidance is appreciated. My SQL skills are lacking and I have tried several solutions without success. Anyway, I need to create a VIEW for the following query:

```
CREATE VIEW open_orders AS
SELECT
 t1.orderID,
 DATE_FORMAT(t1.orderDate,'%m-%d-%Y') AS orderDate,
 t6.colorName,
 t1.originID,
 t1.rackNumber,
 t2.locationNumber AS originNumber,
 t2.locationName AS originName,
 t3.locationName AS destinationName,
 t4.locationStatusName,
 COUNT(t5.orderID) AS totalCount
FROM `order` AS t1
JOIN `location` AS t2 ON t1.originID = t2.locationID
JOIN `location` AS t3 ON t1.destinationID = t3.locationID
JOIN `locationStatus` AS t4 ON t1.locationStatusID = t4.locationStatusID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `orderItem` WHERE `productStatusID` = 02 OR `productStatusID` = 03) AS t5 ON t1.orderID = t5.orderID
JOIN `color` AS t6 ON t1.requestedColorID = t6.colorID
WHERE t1.orderStatusID = 01
GROUP BY t1.orderID
ORDER BY t1.orderDate DESC, t1.orderID DESC;
```

The problem is with the subquery. Because I can't use a subquery within the FROM statement I attempted to use a VIEW. However, the table is large and this approach causes too much of a performance issue.

I'm sure there is a way I can accomplish this without using a VIEW or subquery but am having trouble coming up with a solution.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.

```
...
LEFT JOIN orderItem AS t5
       ON t5.orderID = t1.orderID
      AND t5.productStatusID IN (02,03)
JOIN color ...
```

This does the same thing as your query, but more efficiently since it avoids the derived table.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much Michael!!